# Integration of multiplication of matrices

Tags: integration, matrices

I need to calculate an integration in a finite element procedure. The integration is in this form:

$$\iiint E(y,z)A(x)B(y,z)C(x)D(y,z)dxdydz.$$

Here, $E(y,z)$, $B(y,z)$  and $D(y,z)$  are matrices dependent on $y$ and $z.$ $A(x)$ and $C(x)$ are matrices only dependent on $x.$ I have the explicit expressions for $A(x)$ and $C(x)$, and thus I would like to take the $x$-dependent integration out of the equation, which will simplify the integration procedure. Is there any way to achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps write out all of the matrix products explicitly in summation form and see what (if anything) can be shuffled around?

Comment: If you tell us what the matrices look like, it will be easier to answer the question. Also, what is the dimension of each matrix? I'm assuming the product $EABCD$ is a scalar?

Comment: E is a 80*15 (dimension) matrix, A is a 15*3 matrix, B is a 3*6 matrix, C is a 6*15 matrix, and D is a 15*80 matrix. The product EABCD is a 80*80 matrix. The integration is carried out to each element of the matrix. In a finite element procedure, Gauss scheme can be used to calculate the integration numerically without working out the explicit summation form of the matrices. I don't think it is feasible to work out the summation form either, given the size of the matrices.

Comment: I am asking this, because both A(x) and C(x) have explicit polynomial forms, and if these two items can be taken out of the equation, then the algorithm could be executed much faster, which is apparent.

Comment: These matrices are stiffness and mass matrices etc for dynamic problems. I have rearranged the shape functions, so that they are not the conventional stiffness and mass matrices. Nevertheless, they have similar forms.